# How to use dynamic api in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-sheets, next.js

am new in next JS, I am using google sheet as a backend, google sheet data display in my output working fine, but I want to display my data output as dynamic Route with JSON format, suppose when I Go throgh http:localhost//api/dynamicid i want to display my data in jSON format, if you have any query in my question ,please free fell to ask.

> sheet.js

```
import { google } from 'googleapis';

export async function getDataFromSheets() {
  try {
    const target = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];
    const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(
      process.env.GOOGLE_SHEETS_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      null,
      (process.env.GOOGLE_SHEETS_PRIVATE_KEY || '').replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
      target
    );

    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: jwt });
    const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId: process.env.SPREADSHEET_ID,
      range: 'sheet'
    });

    
    const rows = response.data.values;
    if (rows.length) {
      return rows.map((row) => ({
        title: row[0],
        description: row[1],
      }));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  return [];
}
```

> index.js

This is my main page where we seem output

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

import { getDataFromSheets} from './libs/sheets'

export default function Home({data}) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Nextsheet </title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Connecting NextJS with Google Spreadsheets as Database"
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <h1>Welcome to Nextsheet </h1>
        <p>Connecting NextJS with Google Spreadsheets as Database</p>
        <ul>
          {data && data.length ? (
            data.map((item) => (
              <li key={item}>
                {item.title} - {item.description} 
              </li>
            ))
          ) : (
            <li>Error: do not forget to setup your env variables </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
console.log(process.env.NAME);
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
 
  const sheet = await getDataFromSheets();
  return {
    props: {
      data: sheet.slice(0, sheet.length), // remove sheet header
    },
    revalidate: 1, // In seconds
  };
}
```

> dynamicid.js

in this page i want to display my output as an json format

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
    res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
  }
```

Comment: What you mean under "display my data output as dynamic Route with JSON format"? Dynamic routes are [id].js file.

Comment: Why don't you call `const sheet = await getDataFromSheets();` in your API route and return that as JSON?

Comment: @juliomalves can you tell me how can i write?

Comment: @illiachill yes brother

Comment: @illiachill brother can you tell me how can i get result